# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.zopim.android.sdk.model.VisitorInfo.getEmail()' app is forced close

Tags: java, android, kotlin, chat, zendesk

I'm integrating Chat zendesk for my android app & I got this error `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.zopim.android.sdk.model.VisitorInfo.getEmail()'`. 
Any one know about it please let me know the solution.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: First you need to set Visitor info, are you doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do zopim visitor data initialization first :

```
  val visitorData = VisitorInfo.Builder()
                    .name("username")
                    .email("emailAddress")
                    .build()
  ZopimChat.setVisitorInfo(visitorData)
```